# SPA using DurandalJS and laravel

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, durandal

im trying to create a Single Page Website with DurandalJS in the frontend and Laravel as the Backend. Do you think this is a good Idea? 
If yes how would I do the following:

- What would your recommendation for the basic interaction between both frameworks be?
- Would you rather have all the computation done in JS instead of Laravel sending calculated and styled returns?
- How Do I setup Laravels controller in order to only get dynamic Data for, say a Div, instead of a whole page?
- How can I adjust the browser URLs?

I hope I was specific enough, thank You in advance.

Comment: Please head to [Laravel + Durandal = SPA goodness](https://github.com/thelinuxlich/laravel_durandal): A good resource on github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel does not actually care about what framework you use to build the Frontend. Laravel is just a framework that helps you build your application with. It gives you great advantage with respect to the time spent and effort.

You can use any frontend framework that you want to build your app with. I have actually not used Durandal, but from the first look of it here is my opinion.

- Durandal is built on top of `jQuery, knockoutJS and requireJS`. It also has a `MV*` architecture in place with support for eventing as well. So you could basically define routes on Laravel and initiate the communication between both the frameworks through events and ajax. Again this completely depends on the functionality that you are building.
- In the overall flow of your app, consider Laravel as a Model that just gives data from a source to your app and Durandal as your views and controllers. This way, it will keep your data flow cleaner and easier to build. Computation of your functionality depends on how important and secretive the app is. If there are functionalities/implementations that you need to be secretive about, you can keep it on Laravel and just send computed data to Durandal. If its a web app that you are building, then keeping all implementation on the JS is just a right click away from knowing what and how you have built it. One can just see how the implementation is done just looking at the Javascript source of the web app. If you are building Mobile Device App, then the case is different.
- Take a look at [Restful Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers). Will give you an idea on how to setup controllers to return only data. But if you need to return the `div` itself, then you can make use of the Basic Controllers of Laravel to perform them.
- You can setup cleaner routes for the browser URL's. Take a look at [Laravel Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing)